# Where does a question about deciding between two pieces of hardware go?

Tags: discussion

I'm deciding between two graphic cards to buy and I'd like to ask a question regarding this, so that experienced users can help me.

Where does such a question belong to? Here at super user? At any other SE site? Nowhere?

Comment: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: It belongs on a hardware/overclocking discussion forum, which is *not* what Super User is.  That being said, do your own research - look up the specs, look up benchmarks/reviews, etc.  There will almost always be the comparison you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

> Nowhere

would be right. You could drop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) to discuss about it though.

Answer (score 5):

To extend upon what Sathya ♦ said:

If you are comparing two specific models, your question will very likely be closed as *too localized*. If you ask about how you choose between models, without mentioning a specific one (but rather technolgoies or specifications involved), this should be fine.